# Cannot set OAuth2Permissions for Azure Application Registration in Graph PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

What is the correct format for the value used for setting OAuth2Permissions in the Update-MgApplication/New-MgApplication cmdlets (to update the scopes in the "Scopes defined by this API" section of the "Expose an API" page)?

It appears from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/new-mgapplication?view=graph-powershell-1.0) that the Oauth2PermissionScopes object needs to be set via the -Api parameter, using a IMicrosoftGraphApiAppliction object that contains the Oauth2PermissionScopes object as an object/array of type IMicrosoftGraphPermissionScope[].

This is what I've tried:

```
$appRegName = "My App Reg"
$userConsentDisplayName = "Access $($appRegName)"
$userConsentDescription = "Allow the application to access $($appRegName) on your behalf."
$adminConsentDisplayName = "Access $($appRegName)"
$adminConsentDescription = "Allow the application to access $($appRegName) on behalf of the signed-in user."    

$oauth2PermissionsScopes = @{
    Oauth2PermissionScopes = @{
        AdminConsentDescription = $adminConsentDescription
        AdminConsentDisplayName = $adminConsentDisplayName
        UserConsentDescription  = $userConsentDescription
        UserConsentDisplayName  = $userConsentDisplayName
    }
}
$api = @{
    Api = $oauth2PermissionsScopes
}
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $clientAadApplication.Id -Api $api
#^Causes this error: "A resource without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."

$oauth2PermissionsScopes = @{
    Oauth2PermissionScopes = @{
        AdminConsentDescription = $adminConsentDescription
        AdminConsentDisplayName = $adminConsentDisplayName
        UserConsentDescription  = $userConsentDescription
        UserConsentDisplayName  = $userConsentDisplayName
    }
}
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $clientAadApplication.Id -Api $oauth2PermissionsParams
#^This doesn't generate an error, but nothing is set. The body of the PATCH request shows as (and generates a 204 No Content response):
#{
#  "api": {
#    "oauth2PermissionScopes": [ ]
#  }
#}
```

What is wrong with my format or usage of the cmdlet parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the format of the parameter to ensure a proper hash table (as per the answer from @user2250152) is a partial fix. The main issue when setting OAuth2 permission scopes that don't already exist in the Application Registration is the requirement to set additional properties other than the *Description and *DisplayName fields (Id, IsEnabled, Type and Value is also required):

```
$apiApplication = @{
    oauth2PermissionScopes = @(
        @{
            AdminConsentDescription = $adminConsentDescription
            AdminConsentDisplayName = $adminConsentDisplayName
            UserConsentDescription  = $userConsentDescription
            UserConsentDisplayName  = $userConsentDisplayName
            Id                      = New-Guid
            IsEnabled               = $true
            Type                    = "User"
            Value                   = "user_impersonation"
        }
    )
}

#$clientAadApplication variable is set 'off-script' (must use the Id of the Application Registration set to that variable from Get-MgApplication or as a result of New-MgApplication)
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $clientAadApplication.Id -Api $apiApplication
```

Answer (score 1):

`apiApplication` has property `Oauth2PermissionScopes` which is an array of `IMicrosoftGraphPermissionScope`.

You need to build a hash table with an array

```
$apiApplication = @{
    oauth2PermissionScopes = @(
        # first item
        @{
            AdminConsentDescription = $adminConsentDescription
            AdminConsentDisplayName = $adminConsentDisplayName
            UserConsentDescription  = $userConsentDescription
            UserConsentDisplayName  = $userConsentDisplayName
        }
    )
}

Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $clientAadApplication.Id -Api $apiApplication
```

For validation you can run `$apiApplication | ConvertTo-Json` to check how the json will look like.

```
{
    "oauth2PermissionScopes": [
      {
          "UserConsentDescription":  null,
          "AdminConsentDescription":  null,
          "AdminConsentDisplayName":  null,
          "UserConsentDisplayName":  null
      }
   ]
}
```

Similar for `New-MgApplication`

```
$params = @{
    DisplayName = "My App",
    Api = @{
        Oauth2PermissionScopes = @(
            @{
                AdminConsentDescription = $adminConsentDescription
                AdminConsentDisplayName = $adminConsentDisplayName
                UserConsentDescription  = $userConsentDescription
                UserConsentDisplayName  = $userConsentDisplayName
            }
        )
}

New-MgApplication -BodyParameter $params
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error: "New-MgApplication : Property  value is required but is empty or missing.". It looks like it is trying to log an empty Property name. I get the same error when I try Update-MgApplication. Have you tested this?