# Adding Scopes to Azure AD Application with Powershell (Expose an API)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-app-registration

I'd like to add a Scope to an Azure AD App / Service Principal (UI=Expose an API) with Powershell.

```
$app = New-MgApplication -DisplayName $name -SignInAudience "AzureADMyOrg"
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $app.id -IdentifierUris @("api://$($app.AppId)")

$oauth_permission_scopes = @{
        AdminConsentDescription = "admin desc"
        AdminConsentDisplayName = "admin name"
        Type = "Admin"
        Value = "Read.all"
        Id = $([guid]::NewGuid())
    }
$sp = New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId -Notes $description -Tags @("HideApp","WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp")  #HideApp=VisibleToUsers
Update-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $sp.Id -Oauth2PermissionScopes $oauth_permission_scopes
```

But i get the message:

```
Update-MgServicePrincipal_UpdateExpanded1: Property 'oauth2PermissionScopes' is read-only and cannot be set.
```

Can this only be added in the UI?!

Comment: I don't have one to test with at the moment, but based on the `Update-MgServicePrincipal` help page, you may need to go up one level and update the `-Api` object like the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74778773/7411885

Comment: Hi Cpt.Whale, this perfectly answered my question. I’ve read the help page, but I didn’t understand the part “For more information see the oauth2PermissionScopes property on the application entity's api property.“. Now I get it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I ran the same code as you to add scopes and got **same error** as below:

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, application is created but **scope** not added like below:

[image]

To add **`scope`** to Azure AD Application with PowerShell (Expose an API), you need to modify your script as suggested by **Cpt.Whale** like this:

```
$api = @{
    oauth2PermissionScopes = @(
        @{
        AdminConsentDescription = "admin desc"
        AdminConsentDisplayName = "admin name"
        Type = "Admin"
        Value = "Read.all"
        Id = $([guid]::NewGuid())
    }
    )
}

Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $app.id -Api $api
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **scope** added successfully in `Expose an API` tab of Azure AD application as below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sridevi, thanks for your confirmation. I was too stuck on the wrong object - since it was not marked as read only in the documentation.